# Measurable Set From Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $D$ is a measurable set and that for each integer $n \geq 1$, $f_n : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function. Prove the set
$$E = \{x \in D \mid (f_n(x))_{n \geq 1} \text{ converges}\}$$
is measurable.

I know that $E$ is the set of all Cauchy sequences $(f_n(x))_{n \geq 1}$ and that for each $n$, $f_n^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for each open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
E = \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq 1} \bigcap_{l \geq k} (f_k - f_l)^{-1}([-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}])
$$